# Call JS function with attributes from another file

Tags: javascript, function

I have a JS file with a simple function, matching width\heights of divs.
How can I call this function using attributes from HTML file.

In other words, I want to write a function matchHeight(div1,div2) in an outside file but call it from wherever i want using the divs I want.

The function exists, I just don't know how to call it the way I want.

Sorry if I didn't explain myself clearly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write your `MatchHeights(d1,d2){ ... }` function in a `JS` file and link the file in your `HTML` page like you normally would link any `JS` file, then you can call the `function` in any part of your page, as long as you call the function after the linked file has been loaded by the browser.

Infact, you could even call it in other `JS` files, as long as the original containing file is loaded before the other ones by the browser.

To get the `function` to run the moment the page loads, call the `function` in the `onload` event of the `body` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var div1 = (some code to get the element)
var div2 = (some code to get the element)
</script>
...
...
<body onload="matchHeight(div1,div2)">
```

Answer (score 1):

You must link the .js file in your .html file like this:

```
<head>
 <script src="yourJSFile.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body onLoad="yourFunction();">
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

A really common pattern in jQuery that you can apply is passing in the CSS selector. It's easiest if you can just pass in the div's IDs, but other solutions will work also.

First off take any arguments out of your init string. It's way to complicated. Try this instead:

`<body onload="init()">`

```
function init() {
  matchHeight("id1", "id2");
}
```

Once you have that you get the actual div in those functions like this:

```
function matchHeight(id1, id2) {
  var div1 = document.getElementById(id1)
  var div2 = document.getElementById(id2)
  // .. other stuff
}
```

If you're using jQuery I'd recommend simplifying this even more, by taking the `init()` function off of the body tag completely, replacing it with `jquery(document).load(function() {` and using normal CSS selectors instead....`matchHeight("#id1", "#id2")` and `var $div1 = $(id1);`, but either way will work :)